# await for http request in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am having an issue turning this http request into a promise or something that I can wait for. I need to wait for the response because it contains the record id that was created with the request iself.

the function addChannelField is being called from **ChannelFieldsService**

```
addChannelField(data: any) {
   
    await this.http
      .post<{ message: string; post: any }>(
        BACKEND_URL,
        postData
      ).subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log('responseData', responseData);
        responseData // this is the data I want to return to function calling this function

      })

  }
```

the function is being called from another component using the following line:

```
  this.channelFieldsService.addChannelField(formData)
```

I am tried adding async, await... that did not work.
I think I am suppose to wrap this function in a promise but I cant get it to work

I found this exact question on stackoverflow but they dont show the answer, they only describe it. so i dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
addChannelField(postData: any) {
    const data = await this.http
      .post<{ message: string; post: any }>(
        BACKEND_URL,
        postData
      ).toPromoise()

}
```

More about toPromise: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise

NOTE: `toPromise` is deprecated since version 7.x of rxjs

Answer (score 3):

```js
service.ts
public addChannelField(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<{ message: string; post: any }>(BACKEND_URL, postData);
}

component.ts
this.channelFieldsService.addChannelField(formData)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log(response.id); // something like this
      });
```

Assuming you're using (Angular+TypeScript+RxJS)..
The initial pseudocode would look like this. A service must just return an observable/promise and a component must subscribe to it.
Kindly, consider making this code clean by applying best practices. Good luck!